# ¿conversion a un tipo de dato?

Tags: java

Buenas estoy realizando el mapeo manual de las clases(impuesto), el problema es cuando quiero guardar una entidad .
`

```
public static <T> Object setEntity(T entity, Map<String, String> params) throws Exception {
        Class c = entity.getClass();
        Object o = c.newInstance();
        // Class<?>[] paramTypes2 = {String.class,
        // Integer.class,Double.class,Date.class};
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {

            java.lang.reflect.Field field = c.getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
            //System.out.println("clave=" + entry.getKey() + ", valor=" + entry.getValue());
            Class<?>[] paramTypes = { field.getType() };
            java.lang.reflect.Method method = c.getMethod("set" + entry.getKey(), paramTypes);
            Class typoClass = Class.forName(paramTypes.toString());
            System.out.println("la clases"+typoClass.getName().toString());
            // method.invoke(o, entry.getValue());//aca esta el error parece //que no esta recibiendo el parametro deseado para hacer el "set"
        }

        return o;
    }
```

`

como podria cambiar el tipo de dato requerido?.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que estás haciendo. Lo que me parece un poco raro es que mezcles genéricos con reflection. Usualmente, o haces una cosa o haces la otra, pero no las mezclas.

Comment: lo que estoy haciendo es "mapear" la entidad con sus valores, reflection lo uso para poder acceder a sus "sets"..

Comment: Me gustaria saber que realmente estas haciendo porque si es para mapear base de datos existen tecnicas mas acertadas para darle solucion. Por favor explicar mejor.